# Cart Quantity Issue

Tags: php

I am trying to write a page where I have the following items:

A product category, within the product category unique items to that category, and a qty where a user can select "X" amount of said unique items within each category.

The format would look like this when selected in the cart:

`Item Category
Each unique id of said Category
Qty of Category Ordered`

This is how I have each piece defined.

`$product_name = $_POST["product_name"]` - The Category

`$product_id = $_POST["product_id"];` - The unique identifier of each item within the category.

`$product_qty = $_POST["product_qty"]` - The Quantity Selected

$product_id is a string.  Let's say I have unique IDs of 2,4,6,8, so that when a quantity of 1 is selected, only ID 2 is chosen.  If quantity 4 is selected, then IDs 2,4,6,8 are selected.  Because of this, I make the string into an array using explode so that each ID within the string is unique.

`$product_ids = explode(',', $product_id);`

So all my values are represented, and I can successfully get them from the main page.  But I can't figure out how to make the cart itself function properly.  The category itself should remain static after it is added to the cart unless it is deleted from the cart - only the unique ids within the category should change.  If a user selects quantity 2, but then decides to select quantity 4 instead, I need the cart to add or subtract the appropriate IDs under the one category without adding a new category.  The only time a new category should be added is if the user selects the quantity from another category.  Does anyone know how I can accomplish what I'm trying to do?

EDIT:  Let me paste the cart code, but be gentle with me as this is my first attempt at this.  This is what I am attempting to do, but it doesn't work the way I am wanting it to.  Note that I have a lot of variables defined because I was testing many options.  I don't necessarily need them all.

```
`<?php  
 session_start();
 include_once("config.php");

 //empty cart by distroying current session
 if(isset($_GET["emptycart"]) && $_GET["emptycart"]==1) {
     $return_url = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]); //return url
     session_destroy();
      header('Location:'.$return_url);
  }

 //add item in cart
 if(isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]=='add') {
     $product_name = $_POST["product_name"];
     $product_qty = $_POST["product_qty"];
     $return_url = base64_decode($_POST["return_url"]); //return url
     $product_id = $_POST["product_id"];
     $product_ids = explode(',', $product_id);
     $product_select = implode(',', array_slice($product_ids, 0, $product_qty));
     $product_final = explode(',', $product_select);

     foreach ($product_final as $id) {
         $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$id'");
     }
     $obj = $results->fetch_object();
     if ($results) {
         $new_product = array(array('name'=>$product_name, 'code'=>$id, 'qty'=>$product_qty));
         if(isset($_SESSION["products"])) {
             $found = false;
             foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) {
                 if ($cart_itm["code"] == $id) {
                     $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'qty'=>$product_qty);
                     $found = true;
                 }
                 else {
                     $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"]);
                 }
             }
             if($found == false) {
                 $_SESSION["products"] = array_merge($product, $new_product);
             }
             else {
                 $_SESSION["products"] = $product;
             }
         }
         else {
             $_SESSION["products"] = $new_product;
         }
     }
     header('Location:'.$return_url);
 }
 if(isset($_GET["removep"]) && isset($_GET["return_url"]) && isset($_SESSION["products"])) {
     $id = $_GET["removep"];
     $return_url = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]);
     foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) {
         if($cart_itm["code"]!=$id) {
            $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"]);
         }
         $_SESSION["products"] = $product;
     }
     header('Location:'.$return_url);
 }
 ?>`
```

Another Edit:

A version where I take the $product_select string out of the newly defined array.  The cart functions the way I would want now, but then...how do I pass the $product_select string on to the next page?

```
`<?php  
 session_start();
 include_once("config.php");

 //empty cart by distroying current session
 if(isset($_GET["emptycart"]) && $_GET["emptycart"]==1) {
     $return_url = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]); //return url
     session_destroy();
      header('Location:'.$return_url);
  }

 //add item in cart
 if(isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]=='add') {
     $product_name = $_POST["product_name"];
     $product_qty = $_POST["product_qty"];
     $return_url = base64_decode($_POST["return_url"]); //return url
     $product_id = $_POST["product_id"];
     $product_ids = explode(',', $product_id);
     $product_select = implode(',', array_slice($product_ids, 0, $product_qty));

     $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$product_select'");

     if ($results) {
         $new_product = array(array('name'=>$product_name, 'qty'=>$product_qty));
         if(isset($_SESSION["products"])) {
             $found = false;
             foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) {
                 if ($cart_itm["name"] == $product_name) {
                     $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'qty'=>$product_qty);
                     $found = true;
                 }
                 else {
                     $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"]);
                 }
             }
             if($found == false) {
                 $_SESSION["products"] = array_merge($product, $new_product);
             }
             else {
                 $_SESSION["products"] = $product;
             }
         }
         else {
             $_SESSION["products"] = $new_product;
         }
     }
     header('Location:'.$return_url);
 }
 if(isset($_GET["removep"]) && isset($_GET["return_url"]) && isset($_SESSION["products"])) {
     $product_name = $_GET["removep"];
     $return_url = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]);
     foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) {
         if($cart_itm["name"]!=$product_name) {
            $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"]);
         }
         $_SESSION["products"] = $product;
     }
     header('Location:'.$return_url);
 }
 ?>`
```

Comment: if you want `product_final` to be an array, you do NOT need to `implode` the `array_slice` then `explode` it again. `array_slice` returns an array. `explode` returns an array from a string, `implode` returns a string from an array, you can just do: `$product_final = array_slice($product_ids, 0, $product_qty);`

Comment: Again - the variables are there because I was experimenting.  The issue I have is that whenever "id" is a string, then I end up getting a unique cart addition for each string.  So for example, string 2,4,6,8 is one cart item/category, then string 2,4 becomes another separate one.  I need the cart to function to where if you change the quantity, you don't get an entirely new item/category in the cart...if that makes sense.

Comment: One way I could make the cart function the way I want is to remove the product_id from the newly defined array - it works as expected this way, but how would I pass the product_id onto the next page?  I made an edit to the main post to show the code without having product_id in the newly defined array.

Comment: Well, if your customer would click on "Add to cart" with 10.000 quantity, would you write 10.000 same ids to the stack?

Comment: Could I do what I am trying to accomplish with LIMIT in my SQL query?  Is there a way to pass each QTY of each category to the final page and plug that into a value for LIMIT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out.  So I didn't even need to pass the unique id.  Instead, I removed the product_id from the equation, and in my final result, use LIMIT based on the quantity of the item.  Since the quantity is a string, I convert the string to an int, which allows me to use quantity as a variable in my query.  This gives me the result I need.  Thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 0):

```
$product_name = $_POST["product_name"];

$product_id = $_POST["product_id"];
// let's say "2,4,6,8"

$product_qty = $_POST["product_qty"];
// let's say 3

$product_ids = explode(',', $product_id);
```

$product_ids should now be:

```
array(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 8
)
```

take a slice from the resulting array:

```
$grab_ids = array_slice( $product_ids, 0, $product_qty );
// starting with index 0 take $product_qty
```

$grab_ids should now be

```
array(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 6
)
```

the first argument is the array, the second argument is the key index to start on (0-3), and the third argument is how many to take (1-4).

you can perform additional actions:

```
echo implode( ',', $grab_ids );
// would output as: 2,4,6
```

Comment: I am not certain how this helps with the cart function that I am speaking of.  Do I need to paste my code for that to help explain my issue?

Comment: after you `explode()` a string you have an array -- in your case an array of IDs. it seems you are asking how to get a selection of those IDs based on quantity. look at my revision with more details added, including the correction of starting at the zero index.

Comment: I see - so you would define each quantity with a string value in the final result.  That makes more sense.  Let me see if I can get that working, but not sure if I understand the logic of the cart enough to get it working yet.  I've edited my main post to show what my cart code looks like.

Comment: it only makes more sense if that's what you want. i was just suggesting you could reconvert the array back into a string if yopu wanted to.